# Grid View: getting one column value from other table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, devexpress

I made form for inserting values into DB, and one column is CompanyID, and there is table Companies where that CompanyID is primary key.

How to get like dropdown menu or something, so users don't type like 1213 (ID), but they select it from list, or something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: Use [ASPxComboBox](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBoxtopic) devexpress control.

Comment: But how to combine it with ASPxGridView, which I must use?

Comment: There are numeorus examples on DevExpress site. This is [one](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E134.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the simplest method.
Create & configure a SqlDataSource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyID], [CompanyName] FROM [tbl_Company] ORDER BY [CompanyName]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Drag and drop a dropdown list from the toolbox. set datasourceid, datatext field and data value field.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField = "CompanyID" 
            DataMember="DefaultView" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Run the page.

Answer (score 0):

Select company name and ID from company table in array.
then with that array create your drop down list as follows

```
SQl = "select id, name from company";
echo '<select>'
foreach($companies as $company)
    echo "<option value='$company[id]'>$company['name']</option>";
echo '</select>'
```